# need more input or information regarding binary.write error invalid type xxx

Tags: go

I'm trying to write protobuf *Timestamp.timestamp to binary, and the error I got is `invalid type *Timestamp.timestamp` and I've tried to no avail, can anyone point me to some direction? thanks!

```
    package main

    import (
        "bytes"
        "encoding/binary"
        "fmt"
        google_protobuf "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"
        "time"
    )

    func main() {
        buff := new(bytes.Buffer)

        ts := &google_protobuf.Timestamp{
            Seconds: time.Now().Unix(),
            Nanos:   0,
        }

        err := binary.Write(buff, binary.LittleEndian, ts)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("done")
    }
```

Comment: Would you try using ts without the reference operator "&". I think you are writing the pointer, not the timestamp.

Comment: @Seaskyways: That is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can anyone point me to some direction?

---

Read the error message.

> ```
> binary.Write: invalid type *timestamp.Timestamp
> ```

---

Read the documentation for `binary.Write` and `timestamp.Timestamp`.

> [Package binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/)
>
> `import "encoding/binary"`
>
> [func Write](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write)
>
> ```
> func Write(w io.Writer, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error
> ```
>
> Write writes the binary representation of data into w. Data must be a
>   fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values, or a pointer to such
>   data. Boolean values encode as one byte: 1 for true, and 0 for false.
>   Bytes written to w are encoded using the specified byte order and read
>   from successive fields of the data. When writing structs, zero values
>   are written for fields with blank (_) field names.
>
> [package
>   timestamp](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp)
>
> ```
> import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"
> ```
>
> [type
>   Timestamp](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp#Timestamp)
>
> ```
> type Timestamp struct {
>     // Represents seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch
>     // 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
>     // 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
>     Seconds int64 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=seconds,proto3" json:"seconds,omitempty"`
>     // Non-negative fractions of a second at nanosecond resolution. Negative
>     // second values with fractions must still have non-negative nanos values
>     // that count forward in time. Must be from 0 to 999,999,999
>     // inclusive.
>     Nanos                int32    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=nanos,proto3" json:"nanos,omitempty"`
>     XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
>     XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
>     XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
> }
> ```
>
> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or
>   calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
>   nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time. It is encoded using the
>   Proleptic Gregorian Calendar which extends the Gregorian calendar
>   backwards to year one. It is encoded assuming all minutes are 60
>   seconds long, i.e. leap seconds are "smeared" so that no leap second
>   table is needed for interpretation. Range is from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z. By restricting to that range, we
>   ensure that we can convert to and from RFC 3339 date strings. See
>   https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt.

---

As the error message says: `*timestamp.Timestamp` is not a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values, or a pointer to such data.

To confirm that, comment out the `XXX_unrecognized` variable-sized field; there is no error.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.pb.go
type Timestamp struct {
    // Represents seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch
    // 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
    // 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
    Seconds int64 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=seconds,proto3" json:"seconds,omitempty"`
    // Non-negative fractions of a second at nanosecond resolution. Negative
    // second values with fractions must still have non-negative nanos values
    // that count forward in time. Must be from 0 to 999,999,999
    // inclusive.
    Nanos                int32    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=nanos,proto3" json:"nanos,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    // XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    buff := new(bytes.Buffer)

    ts := &Timestamp{
        Seconds: time.Now().Unix(),
        Nanos:   0,
    }

    err := binary.Write(buff, binary.LittleEndian, ts)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Q5NGnO49Dsc

Output:

```
done
```

Comment: that is a great answer, thank you! but to extend that, I guess besides commenting out the []byte, there's no way that I can work with it, right? since I don't want to modify the original code (source code)?